# Unity3D: Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape) doesn't work on mobile nor PC

Tags: unity-game-engine

this piece of code doesn't work. When I set a breakpoint on the if statement, the debugger breaks. But the `GetKeyDown` never get's triggerd, when pressing Escape or the mobile back button (Android).

```
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape))
        Application.Quit();
}
```

I also tried `if (Input.GetButtonDown("Cancel"))`. Doesn't work either.

I deployed the game to my mobile device. Maybe some settings have been messed up? Another project works just fine (2D Desktop). I also used the Unity Remote App.

I am using Unity 2018.3.0b2?

EDIT: Solved somehow. Unity Remote App maybe was an issue. Back button only works on real Android device.

Comment: Unless there is a new bug we don't yet know about , `Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape)` works on PC and Android. If the debugger breaks on `if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape))`, doesn't it mean it's working? Replace `Application.Quit();` with `Debug.Log("Escape")` and see if there is a log in your Editor.

Comment: Hey, no, when it breaks on the if, it's just before evaluating the statement. It is skipping the block afterwards. But I somehow got it working now. Maybe it had something to do with using Remote App. Building and deplyoing on my mobile device also works (guess the app doesn't send the back button info). Thanks!

Comment: This issue is still present :\ Everything works great, Escape is working in the Editor, and also on Android (= back button). But if Unity Remote is running, none of them works.